# How can I describe this kind of prostration?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, definition

To prostrate, as [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prostrate) says, means:

"If you prostrate yourself, you lie down flat on the ground, on your front, usually to show respect for God or a person in authority"

On the other hand, when we refer to the prostration done by people of some religious communities, we often picture a slightly different position (see pictures below).

[image] [image]

Clearly, in these pictures, the body is not lying down flat on the ground but curled up. So, the questions are:

- If, without any context, I just say that a man prostrated himself on the ground, what prostration would you picture?
- If, as Collins dictionary says, a prostration generally refers to a flat position, how would you describe the specific type of prostration shown in the pictures (without mentioning this or that specific religious community or term)?

Addendum: I found [this description](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/image/1217475001) of a work of art that says  "two men **are kneeling prostrate** before a statue". The picture is quite dark, but the two men looked in the same position as the one described here. It's from the British Museum by the way, so it should be reliable. What do you think of it?

Second addendum: This [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prostrate%20on%20his%20knees%2Ckneeling%20prostrate%2Cprostrate%20on%20her%20knees&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprostrate%20on%20his%20knees%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckneeling%20prostrate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprostrate%20on%20her%20knees%3B%2Cc0) tells us that probably "to be prostrate on one's knees" is even more used. So, for instance, "He **was prostrate on his knees**".

Comment: Without context, it is the first that would come to mind if you said “prostrate”, it is closer to the image of one flinging oneself to the floor. Both are extreme forms of *kneeling*, with one's head to the floor

Comment: A full bow: https://www.learnreligions.com/bowing-as-a-buddhist-practice-450057#:~:text=A%20common%20%22full%22%20bow%20requires,that's%20not%20always%20the%20case.

Answer (score 1):

English freely borrows words for specific things from other cultures.

Prostration would be a general term. You would use this if writing for a general audience, especially if the exact position of the knees and hands is not particularly relevant.

For this specific posture in Muslim prayer the word [Sujud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujud) or Sujood can be used. For the similar posture adopted in Japanese culture [Dogeza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogeza) can be used.

There is no specific unborrowed English word for this posture that distinguishes it from other forms of protration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the picture with the prostrating woman is taken from a Buddhist article. I intentionally put the pictures of different communities to seek a general way to describe the type of prostration being referred to.

Comment: Yes.  "Prostration" would be the general term to use, if writing for a general audience. If you need to describe the particular position of the knees the you need to describe it in a full sentence. What is your purpose?  To teach someone how to do it or to describe the attitude of a person who is doing it.

Comment: I just want to describe that position (not flat on the ground) without any known religious reference. By the way, I added a possible answer in the OP.

Comment: I think prostation goes too far. I'm seeing full bow.

Comment: @Lambie No, a "full bow" is made from a standing position with the waist bent to 90 degrees and the head down.  The specific posture here has a particular  use in Islamic prayer.  You can't separate it from the religious reference

Comment: I do not like prostrate as for me it means going full tilt on the floor. In Buddhism, I's seeing full bow. Dunno about Islam.

Comment: I was referring to the Buddhism only.

Comment: @Lambie - I grew up thinking of an act of showing deep respect by bowing so deeply that the head touches the ground as a **kowtow**. Kowtowing in Western culture tends to mean shamefully abject submission or grovelling.

Comment: Note that the posture is different in the two pictures. If the posture is different then we can understand that the exact posture is not the point.  So "prostrate" still seems like the best word here.  Kowtow has too much figurative and cultural baggage.  The specific terms are appropriate for the the specific contexts but there simply isn't an English word for this exact posture.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I only know the metaphorical meaning: He was kowtowing to his boss. Basically, kissing his arse.

Answer (score 0):

The words in a language generally reflect the environment, culture and practices of the society that uses it.

English is the language of a society that was mainly Christian, and in worship Christians normally kneel and/or bow their heads during prayer, but do not bow their bodies. Because of this, there is no specific word to describe the kneel-and-bow-body position used by Muslims for prayer.

Posts like [this one](http://christ4humanity.blogspot.com/2014/04/7-postures-of-prayer-plus-1-bonus.html) describe the position as [bowing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bow), but this is not unambiguous because bowing also describes bending at the waist while standing. As you mentioned, prostration is completely incorrect because the body must be flat on the floor.

If you wanted to describe this position accurately in English, you would say something like "kneel and bow the body and head until the head touches the floor, with the hands flat on the floor beside the head."